# Inherit DataGridViewColumn is not shown in Properties from the datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I have an custom DataGridViewFormColumn, which inherit from DataGridViewTextBoxColumn, but you can't choose it in the Properties From the Columns in the "Edit Columns" Dialog. Can anyone explaine this?

Comment: The collection editor has to know about the Types available.  Since the DGV designer/column collection editor is internal your may be left with adding them manually at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

This should work after compiling your solution.
Try to restart Visual if it's still not working after compiling.